# miner.start() cannot deploy my contract

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

My environment:

```
geth 1.8.11
Ethereum Wallet
Mist Browser
Windows 10
```

I tried to deploy a new contract in the Ethereum Wallet.
I executed  (`miner.start();`)  in the Geth JavaScript console to get some ether. Then, to deploy the contract, I started mining again using (`miner.start();`)

(I'm following this tutorial https://codeburst.io/build-your-first-ethereum-smart-contract-with-solidity-tutorial-94171d6b1c4b).

But when I started mining, the number of ether continued to increase and the number of confirmation did not increase and hence the contract cannot be deployed

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use ganache which is a part of truffle framework for developing DAPP, once the code is tested you can think about deploying it on the blockchain network. If you want to deploy smart contract on private ethereum blockchain network then, you can pre-allocate some ethers to a specific account.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2019, Mist is deprecated. So better use Metamask wallet instead of Mist.
Also use Ganache and truffle instead of Geth because you can find more support online for these.

Also you can deploy with truffle on any test networks like Ropsten, Kovan etc., but I suggest you use ganache because it is more faster as it has auto mining.

And also maybe follow this tutorial for using Ganache and truffle and deploying dApps: 
 [Dappuniversity tutorial](https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/how-to-build-a-blockchain-app)

I am only suggesting this because this is a space that is updating by the day and there is no use learning about things that are deprecated.

Also new here so any suggestions are appreciated!! Thanks!